# How to assign a binary zero character to a variable in python?

Tags: python, perl

Like in perl we do:

```
use constant MSG_TERMINATOR => "\0";
```

where MSG_TERMINATOR is a variable.

What is the way of do the same in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply define a variable:

```
MSG_TERMINATOR = "\0"
```

Comment: @RishabhSoni:  `\00` and `\0` are both valid octal character specifications, `\x00` specifies the value as hexadecimal.  See [Escape Sequences in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C).